# Using Singleton Design with Inheritance in a multithreaded Application

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance, design-patterns, singleton

I am having an application where code is somewhat written like this

```
public Interface SuperCLass{
//....to do some methods
}

public class BaseClass1 implements SuperCLass{
//....to do some methods
}

public class BaseClass2 implements SuperCLass{
//....to do some methods
}
```

Now in my application only one object can be instantiated for SuperClass reference, i.e a synchronized singleton.

Now, I can include

```
public static synchronized  SuperCLass getInstance(){
   //initialise
}
```

in any of the base classes, but I cannot include this declaration in SuperClass interface due to which I cannot get back instance of base class using reference of super class.
e.g.
I want to do this(its a very vague example)

```
BaseClass1 bc1 = BaseClass1.getInstance();

SuperClass sc = bc1.getInstance();
```

Now somewhere later in the code

```
bc1=sc.getInstance();
```

How can this be achieved?

Note: Several threads would be accessing these objects hence synchronisation is mandatory

Comment: Why do you want to explicitly cast to `SuperClass`? `BaseClass1` inherits the "interface".

Comment: Your question is unclear, but just putting `synchronized` on the singleton factory method definitely doesn't make your singleton thread-safe.

Comment: Your statement "get back instance of base class using reference of super class" is unclear.

Comment: @Smutje yeah thats right, but somewhere in the application I had to refer that Object through superclass only as we might not be aware of the instance. we can use instanceOf operator in that case, but i was trying to avoid that

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yeah i know that... thats just for examplpe only... in actual i will anclude lock on the object

Comment: @NishantShreshth e.g.
BaseClass1 bc1 = BaseClass1.getInstance();
SuperClass sc = bc1.getInstance();
and now somewhere in code..
bc1=sc.getInstance();

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using singletons why dont you use dependency injection eg: google guice.

Guice will create the instance of the super class for you and then you can access it via the injector.getInstance() method.

Comment: Not sure about google juice... But I am not having very complex/application, so I am avoiding using any external framework...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have to synchronize the access to the instance. There are plenty of examples on how to do that (such as thread safe publishing of a read only or threadsafe class).

Because a singleton means a static method. You have to decide which implementation is used somewhere. Normally this is through a `setInstance` method.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make a Superclass method return a Subclass type is through Generics.

You will not be able to make the methods `static` as you cannot override `static` methods so this technique will not help you but it would go something like:

```
public interface SuperClass<T extends SuperClass<T>> {

    public T getInstance();
}

public class BaseClass1 implements SuperClass<BaseClass1> {

    @Override
    public BaseClass1 getInstance() {
        // Do my create.
    }
}
```

However, for your specific need of requiring thread-safe Singletons extending a base class you could use an `enum` as a factory for them and use a [Multiton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25908117/823393) to ensure there is only ever one of them.